NPM Run Build from shell_exec not working giving sh: vite: command not found
I am trying to run "npm run build" from a function whenever user change a color
dd(shell_exec('cd .. && npm run build 2>&1'));

The output is
sh: vite: command not found

When I try to run "npm run build" directly from ssh, it is working. I need it to working in a function as user can edit theme based on their needs. Thank you
